# Windows 10: will drivers installed using testmode still work then testmode is disabled?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, digital-signature

I have a general understanding problem with Windows Testmode and how to install unsigned drivers: I understand that if I have drivers (in my case for an USB to RS232 serial adapter) that are not digitally signed by the vendor, I can boot Windows into testmode using for example

```
bcdedit /set testsigning on
```

these drivers can be installed, and this actually works in my current case.

However, the thing I am not really sure about is what will happen if I disable testsigning afterwards using

```
bcdedit /set testsigning off
```

In theory, as far as I understand, the drivers should stop working. But practically, what I find on my Windows 10 x64 Pro testsystem is that the drivers are still fully functional. Windows also shows the drivers as not digitally signed in device manager, but still uses them, without any warning.

My question simply is: is that the way it is intended to work (i.e. install drivers in testmode, and the functionality will be persistent even if I reboot into normal mode), or am I having some strange side effect here?